# react-three-fiber scene background brighter than original image

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

My react-three-fiber background is supposed to be a dark starry sky. But in the scene it is very bright. Here is the original image:
[image: Original issues image]

This is the code for the skybox:

```
const { scene } = useThree();

const texture = useLoader(TextureLoader, "textures/skybox.jpg");

scene.background = texture;
```

This is what the scene rendered:

[image: Image of the scene]

(Don't worry about the blurriness. It is just because I took a screen shot of such a small area of my screen.)

I am asking about the brightnessI asked in the Poimandres Discord server and one of the admins said that it may be an encoding error and to ask here.

---

### Edit:

Thanks to Marquizzo for solving the issue. I just added `texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;` and the background became this:

[image: Fixed background]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be an issue with your [texture color space property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.colorSpace). By default textures use THREE.NoColorSpace, but for a straight background JPG that doesn't interact with lighting you could use sRGB.

```js
const texture = useLoader(TextureLoader, "textures/skybox.jpg");
texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
scene.background = texture;
```

Comment: Does this encoding method also apply with the webp format? I use it now as I heard many times that it is better for websites.

Comment: I don't know. That's a different question altogether. Try it out with WEBP and see if what results you get! :)

Comment: Yes, LDR image formats (PNG, JPEG, WebP, AVIF...) are almost always sRGB. If you're using an HDR format (HDR, EXR...) then they're likely to be Linear-sRGB instead, and would use THREE.LinearSRGBColorSpace. That's a generalization and not a rule, so check where you're getting the image if possible.